# Business Training Log

Tags: document-management

I'm looking for software that will allow me to log the training progress for members of staff in a business of approximate 50 employees.

We currently run a network on [SBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_Essentials) 2011.

The staff will often be performing physical activities as well as IT based activities (i.e., there will be oversight away from the software).

Ideally it should allow for logging of progress on a given topic, and for a line manager to sign off that the employee is competent in that topic.

The training materials themselves can be held elsewhere or in the software - I don't mind which.